# Минимальная стоимость умножения матриц

Tags: java

Дана последовательность из n матриц A0 An-1, которые требуется умножить. Размер матрицыA i составляет mi * mi+1.

Требуется найти порядок умножения, минимизирующий общую стоимость умножения. Предположим, что стоимость умножения матриц p × q и q × r равна p · q · r.

Input: n - количество матриц, n + 1 целых чисел m0,m1,...mn (1<= mi <= 1000), размер i-ой матрицы = mi * mi-1

Output: Минимальная стоимость умножения n матриц

Пример: 
Input: 
4

40 20 30 10 30

Output: 26000
  Т.е. есть четыре матрицы, размерами 40x20, 20x30, 30x10 и10x30.
 Назовем их A, B, C, D.  Минимальное количество
   умножений получится путем расстановки скобок следующим образом
  (A(BC))D --> 20*30*10 + 40*20*10 + 40*10*30

Написала код на основе одного найденного, вылетает один из автоматических тестов("неправильный ответ"), не могу понять что за тест конкретно. Может кто-нибудь объяснить где ошибка в алгоритме?

```java
public class Matrix {

    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(System.out);

        int n;
        n = in.nextInt();
        int[] m = new int[n + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i <= n; ++i) {
            m[i] = in.nextInt();
        }

        long result = MatrixChainOrder(m, n + 1);
        // your code

        out.println(result);

        out.close();
    }
static long MatrixChainOrder(int p[], int n) 
    { 

        int m[][] = new int[n][n]; 
        int i, j, k, L, q; 

        for (i = 1; i < n; i++) 
            m[i][i] = 0; 

        for (L=2; L<n; L++) 
        { 
            for (i=1; i<n-L+1; i++) 
            { 
                j = i+L-1; 
                if(j == n) continue; 
                m[i][j] = Integer.MAX_VALUE; 
                for (k=i; k<=j-1; k++) 
                { 
                    q = m[i][k] + m[k+1][j] + p[i-1]*p[k]*p[j]; 
                    if (q < m[i][j]) 
                        m[i][j] = q; 
                } 
            } 
        } 

        return m[1][n-1]; 
    } 

}
```

- дз, не соревнование

Comment: данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что адресовать его стоит автору «автоматических тестов, которые не проходят».

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы код писали на основе псевдокода из Кормена, а там используется нумерация массивов **с единицы**, а не с нуля. Однако входной массив (размерности матриц `p[]` ) индексируется от 0 до n включительно

Поэтому проще завести массив размером n+1 и поправить пределы на `<=`.
Произведение размерностей может быть велико, типы нужно поправить на long

```
    int m[][] = new long[n+1][n+1]; 
    int i, j, k, L; 
    long q;

    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) 
        m[i][i] = 0; 

    for (L=2; L <= n; L++) 
    { 
        for (i=1; i<=n-L+1; i++) 
        { 
            j = i+L-1; 
            m[i][j] = Long.MAX_VALUE; 
            for (k=i; k<=j-1; k++) 
            { 
                q = m[i][k] + m[k+1][j] + p[i-1]*p[k]*p[j]; 
                if (q < m[i][j]) 
                    m[i][j] = q; 
            } 
        } 
    } 

    return m[1][n];
```

Comment: а можно поподробнее? Я как раз путалась в циклах, и только при таких значениях получилось хоть какие-то правильные ответы получить

Comment: Ну вот первый цикл, чтобы заполнить всю диагональ, должен стартовать с нуля, например

Comment: я сначала тоже при таких значениях делала, потом на q = m[i][k] + m[k+1][j] + p[i-1]*p[k]*p[j];  выпадает arrayindexoutofbound

Comment: Да, всё не так просто ;) `p`-то у них с нуля нумеруется и длиной `n+1`. Тогда Вам будет проще сделать таблицы размером n+1 , нулевые строки не использовать, и циклы с книжной индексацией сделать

Comment: вылетает на том же тесте, что и программа в вопросе

Comment: Вызов так должен быть: `  long result = MatrixChainOrder(m, n);` Для примера выдаёт 26000? Для n=1 выдаёт 0?

Comment: да, я поняла, это при таком вызове и не работало. 50% тестов на сайте проходит и из примера тоже

Comment: Произведение размерностей в long вмещается? И `m` и `q`почему `int`, а не `long`?

Comment: если их поставить long, то результат выдает 0 при любых входных данных. При этом поменяла Integer.MAX_VALUE тоже на long

Comment: Этого (0 при любых входных данных) не должно быть никак, какие-то ещё ошибки внесены. Приведите текущий код в вопросе

Comment: не смогла понять почему 0 выводит, в итоге вернула исходный код, заменила на long и все заработало. Спасибо!